# Maven transitive dependency not found. Leads to build error

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a Java project with Maven. My pom.xml includes mainly dependencies, some of which have their own transitive depedencies.

When I run 'mvn compile' most dependencies are loaded fine, but some of the transitive ones are not found, giving the warning "[WARNING] The POM for artifact_name is missing, no dependency information available". This leads to the Maven compile to fail.

The logs show, that the dependencies have been searched from Maven and Jboss public repositories.

1. What can I do in this situation, when a transitive dependency is not found?
2. How can I determine what dependency requires this transitive dependency? Command 'mvn dependency:tree' does not work, as it ends in build failure

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I decided to delete all changes made to the pom.xml and downloaded the original one. After that the warnings with the transitive dependencies went away. So it seems that the issue was possibly with the syntax or some other change in the pom.xml.

Comment: You possibly have a syntax error in your `pom.xml`. Consider sharing it.

Comment: Are you sure the `WARNING` is the problem? I think it is only a warning and not the actual source of your build failure. Can you add the Maven output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to delete all changes made to the pom.xml and downloaded the original one from our repository. After that the warnings with the transitive dependencies went away. So it seems that the issue was probably with the syntax or some other change in the pom.xml